# Redirect URL and change URL parameter value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, parameters

I'm trying to do a `.htaccess` redirect with a parameter but it's not working. Seems like my regex are also wrong. :(

```
https://example.com/art.php?link=456
```

Target URL :

```
https://example.com/art.php?link=789
```

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} link=456
RewriteRule link=789 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} link=456
> RewriteRule link=789 [L,R=301]
> ```

The first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive is the URL-path you need to match, ie. `/art.php` (except there is no slash prefix when used in `.htaccess`). You also need to specify the *substitution* (target URL) as the second argument (which happens to be the same: `/art.php`).

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^link=456$
RewriteRule ^art\.php$ /art.php?link=789 [L,R=301]
```

If you've previously experimented with 310 (permanent) redirects then you'll likely need to clear your browser cache before testing. Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

You can save repetition of the URL parts by using backreferences. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(link)=456$
RewriteRule ^art\.php$ /$0?%1=789 [L,R=301]
```

Where `$0` is the URL-path that the entire `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches. And `%1` contains the match from the parenthesised subpattern in the last matched *condition*.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule